# Why is it easier to write answers than comments without enough reputation?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, reputation, new-users

As someone who isn't confident enough to provide answers, I often find myself wanting to post a comment. Why is posting answers easier than posting comments?

I've been struggling to get enough reputation and I imagine that many other people that want to start contributing might do too. It feels really weird being a member for over 5 years and seeing myself struggling to interact with questions that are relevant for me at the time.

Is posting questions the way to go at the beginning? I think I am missing something.

Comment: You could just edit some posts to get the 50 rep to comment.

Comment: You'll get my Upvote if you add a Dot at the end of your "*I think I am missing something[+.]*"... // And I posted a [Comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424168/why-is-it-easier-to-write-answers-than-comments-without-enough-reputation#comment953930_424170) to one of the Answers, meant a bit as "Support"... // But yep indeed, the Site is completely meant/designed for "Askers" and absolutely not for "Answerers"...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Why is it easier to write answers than comments without enough reputation?

Because we need more **answers**, not **comments**. Our goal is to, literally (from the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which I recommend taking since the lack of the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge on your profile suggests you haven't read it):

> build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming

Hence, there are incentives (reputation points) for posting new answers and disincentives (reputation threshold) for posting comments. And we do, indeed, need more answers, just take a look at the discrepancy between questions posted and answered ([SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1456152/trend-of-questions-asked-last-year-posted-closed-answered-accepted-and-delet#graph)):

[image]

Comment: @dev0T NP - not that the tour itself is very useful given its current state, but it does help in understanding some of the most important fundamentals of SO model as a library of knowledge (as opposed to, say, tech forums). Don't worry, given your area of interest seems to lie in prominent tags, even a couple of decent answers will grant you the "comment everywhere" privilege.

Comment: "*Because we need more answers, not comments.*", yep very clever, ah-ah...!, easy to say when you answer a "large" Tag, but *sometimes* you need to be able to ask for Clarification before you can post an Answer, => simply asking for what Version the OP is using, maybe... :idea:  // (SME (and the only one (active) on the Site (in the last 2-3 years)) in the "small" Tag I answer, it also took me about 3 years to reach the 50-Rep Threshold before I could ask Users about their FCI... (FCI = Full Config Info) (And I refuse to answer when Users don't mention their FCI, => **Catch-22**...!))

Comment: "just take a look at the discrepancy between questions posted and answered" It gets a bit better if you subtract out the closed ones (since, hopefully, questions get closed *before* someone tries an answer). And we **aren't nearly good enough at closing questions**. Tons of questions are terrible and **should not** be answered. The incoming answer rate is fine, the rep thing is more about people not treating the site as a discussion forum.

Answer (score 14):

### Posting answers is the way to go.

Comments are a tool for requesting clarification, not for posting answers or partial answers or trying to help. Just find a question that is clarified enough for you to provide an answer and start answering. You'll be able to comment to request clarification in no time.

Answer (score 5):

[Comments are suggesting soliciting clarifications, constructive criticism, or other minor info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Often for question posts, they're used to soliciting more information (details/clarity). If you don't have the [privilege to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (50rep) but have the [privilege to flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (15rep), then you should flag "Needs Improvement > Needs Details / Clarity".

If you actually think you have an answer (and that the question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) but you're just not 100% sure about it, you have two choices: write an answer and let people vet its usefulness by voting, or don't write an answer. That's it. Comments are not for answers.

---

> Is posting questions the way to go at the beginning? I think I am missing something

I've earned most of my rep by answering things, and my first 1K almost entirely by answering bounties (not that I'd recommend that). That's just to say that starting off in reg-gain by asking questions is not the only way to start out. Maybe what you're missing is the subject-matter-expertise to answer questions in your tags? In that case, just take the time to sharpen your skills and know-how and build up some experience / familiarity with the technologies you use. See also [my answer to "Are there any tricks for finding beginner questions on a network site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388326/997587)

Comment: ... Are you also "starball" then? Or...

Comment: About the vetting, it may be worth noting that comments can only be *upvoted* (or flagged), not *downvoted* and that often generates long noisy debates in the comment section until some moderator move the whole pile to chat.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel [yep](https://youtu.be/lOAKD053Rjo).

Comment: @Bob__ IMX, downvotes never stopped anyone from getting into an argument. Quite the opposite, really.

Comment: @Bob__ I don't see how that's relevant- at least to what I wrote... I was talking about _answering_ there- not comments.

Answer (score -3):

I want to reiterate on the "comments are not for answer". No, they're not - in principle.

If you are unsure of your answer, or if you don't have time to type a full-fledged answer, sure, drop a hint in comments. This is beneficial for everyone.

Just consider that anyone can then write an answer based on your comment and reap the sweet, sweet reputation points, or that it can be removed at any time.

See also:

- [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

---

That being said: why do you feel you need to earn more reputation? Why do you want to post answers you're unsure of? Perhaps you lack the experience to be teaching others; then you shouldn't go post answers with the sole goal of earning more rep.

So it's good you're refraining from posting answers. Get more experience in the tech first, then try to post answers you're more sure of.